# Bulk Inserting Products directly into Drupal's Database

Tags: database, drupal, product, drupal-commerce

I am trying to use Drupal Commerce (Kickstart 2.0) to display variations of a product on a page. I need a way to mass import these products instead of typing out x number of products in Drupal's GUI. I have tried the Feeds module however it is too limited for our needs. We are at the point of inserting data directly into Drupal's tables. Has anyone tried adding products and their variations without seeing a single GUI interface.  Any information or insight would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: The one option I can see is build a custom script which will use Drupal API and insert those data directly to respective tables in database. The script must be provided with a source file form which it will read the product details.